# Multiple taxonomies in archives

Tags: php, archive, taxonomy

I want `archives.php` to be able to show multiple custom taxonomies at once.

Right now this works if I write either

```
domain.com/?taxonomy=red&taxonomy2=circle
```

or

```
domain.com/?taxonomy=red+blue
```

But how do I make my list of taxonomies link correctly to this? Right now I'm only able to get `domain.com/?taxonomy=red` and not add anything else to the URL.

The sidebar on archives.php contains the following code:

```
<?php

//First Query for Posts matching term1
$custom_terms = get_terms('taxonomy');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array('post_type' => 'taxonomy',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            'orderby' => 'title'
        ),
    ),
 );

 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 if($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $custom_term, $taxonomy ).'">'.$custom_term-       >name.'</a>';
    echo '</li>';
 }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please include the PHP code you're referencing.

Comment: Ive updated the original question